# JavaScript Regular Expression to repeat element match in string

Tags: javascript, regex

Yes I am a newbie, I have looked online and cannot seem to find the answer to the following, I know it must be simple.

I have a simple string and need to match spaced Capitals eg T G D ......repeater,
Secondly I need to match capitals with a dot between them and no space eg T.G.D ........repeater

I have the current string = str.match(/ [A-Z] [A-Z] | [A-Z].[A-Z]/g)

but this will only match the first two e.g  **T G**  I Need it to match wherever it finds the following pattern eg T G D E F L ...repeater as a one match

Likewise It will only match the T.G but nothing after e.g **T.G** I Need to match **T.G.D.L.T** repeater (may end with a dot and may not)

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you have a sequence of mixed . and space seperators, would they be all part of the same match or not?

Answer (score 0):

You might use a capturing group matching either a dot or a space in a character class `([. ])`

Match the first 2 capitals and capture the space or dot in group 1. Then optionally repeat what is captured using a back reference  followed by a captital A-Z.

```
\b[A-Z]([. ])[A-Z](?:\1[A-Z])*\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `[A-Z]([. ])[A-Z]` Match A-Z, capture in **group 1** matching either space or `.`
- `(?:\1[A-Z])*` Repeat 0+ times matching what it captured in group 1 followed by A-Z
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r0UV7X/1)

Comment: Thankyou very much that worked great, as a newbie I was trying different combinations for the last two hours. just joined the network :)

Comment: @PTEK Welcome to SO :-)  If you want to match the optional dot at the end, you could add an optional backreference `\b[A-Z]([. ])[A-Z](?:\1[A-Z])*\1?` https://regex101.com/r/yYL3xO/1 If the matches can be after each other, you can use capturing groups as well, for example take group 1 (highlighted in green) in this example `(?:^| )([A-Z]([. ])[A-Z](?:\2[A-Z])*\2?)(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/Pcty1L/1/